# API Understanding made with codeigniter

Tags: php, api, codeigniter

I have bought one android application with web service made in codeigniter. There API in this web service is like below.

```html
<?php

if (!defined("BASEPATH"))
    exit("No direct script access allowed");

class Site extends back {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->lang->load("site", "english");
        $this->load->model("site_model", "site");
    }

    //=====================================================================

    public function get_updates($last_author, $last_quote) {
        $this->db->where("_auid > ", $last_author);
        $this->db->where("au_status", 1);
        $result["authors"] = $this->db->get("authors")->result_array();

        $this->db->select("quotes.*, authors._auid, authors.au_status");
        $this->db->from("quotes");
        $this->db->join("authors", "authors._auid = quotes.qu_author AND authors.au_status = 1");
        $this->db->where("_quid > ", $last_quote);
        $this->db->where("qu_status", 1);        
        $result["quotes"] = $this->db->get()->result_array();

        echo json_encode($result);

    }
    
}
```

I am learning php yet. I have made another fresh corephp web service for use. I am not understanding above api and so not able to make similar api for my new web service. Both web service use same database...anyone can please suggest me how can I use above API in my new corephp web service ?

sorry for my bad knowledge.

Thanks

Comment: It seems simple a clear, You should gain a basic knowledge in Codeigniter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is very simple

function `get_updates` get 2 parameter as input

1) $last_author //value of **_auid**(id) field belong to table author

2) $last_quote //value of **_quid**(id) field belong to table quotes

```
$this->db->where("_auid > ", $last_author);
        $this->db->where("au_status", 1);
        $result["authors"] = $this->db->get("authors")->result_array();
```

These lines fetch data from table **author** with matches value of $last_author parameter

And second query fetch data from table **quotes** and it is join with **author** with matches value of $last_quote parameter.

Join is use for smashing two or more tables into a single table.

$last_author and $last_quote is request parameter send from application.

Desired result will be stored in $result and return with json object as response data to application.

Comment: "Smashed"! Lol - do you mean cleverly and gently interleaved and connected in such a way that related and co-indexed data is conjoined to be available to a single data result row. Or driven into each other at high speed littering the data landscape with the ensuing chaotic wreckage.